# How much overhead do read and delivery receipts add to an Exchange network?

Tags: exchange

Are there any decent stats on this?  Is it something that is worth taking into consideration when doing capacity planning for an Exchange implementation?  Any special considerations to take when planning the configurations?

Comment: Heh heh... I would expect to see a decrease in storage in such an Exchange environment where I have a mailbox. I'll delete any messages with read receipt requests without reading them, and w/o sending a "deleted without reading" receipt. I guess you could say that I'm anti-read receipts, since I've seen them used more for political games than for legitimate purposes. (No wonder I can't imagine working at a "normal job"...)

Comment: Heh, yeah.  It's a beautiful option that reads "Never send a response".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think the read and delivery receipts add very little overhead to a server. For all intents and purposes its just another mail and a very small one at that.

If you server is in such a state that it can't handle them, then it probably needs some work doing.

That being said, I don't actually think they are that usefull when sending external to your own domain. Many systems (antispam etc) as well as other peoples email systems, block those type of messages. Also, poorly setup messaging systems can create infinite auto reply / out of office loops if they handle them poorly. I have seen it done. Overspec your kit as normal and you should have no issues handling them.

Comment: Thanks.  This is for internal purposes, I would certainly block them from going out.

Comment: In that case, go for it. No need to turn them off, they will add only small amounts of data to your mail system and internally they are very usefull (just get ready to tell people hoow to turn the notifications off)

Answer (score 1):

Likewise I don't see any issues with them, and I think that if your server is experiencing load as a result of using them, then you've far bigger problems on your hands!

Some general common-sense considerations I would implement would include defaulting use of them to "off" in the client software (nobody likes getting 10,000 read and delivery receipts hitting their mailbox if they send an email to the entire org) and blocking them for external emails (at the very least so that issuing of a read receipt doesn't confirm to a spammer that they have a live email address; I'm dubious about how effective this is, but it seems good practice to me).

I've never seen stats on them, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

We have them enabled in our environment. Almost no one uses them because almost everyone doesn't allow them. Thus, there is no ecosystem to support its usage. Generally speaking, people only want delivery tracking when something has gone wrong somehow or a message has gone unreplied to when the sender knows the recipient is in the office. In the past month I've only seen our VARs use them, and no internal users.